# image_picker crash in android app - Flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker, flutter-image, flutter-android

First of all, I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53716573/15254253) but the issue still going, and I tried it on the new emulator, on a real device but I couldn't fix it.
And it works on IOS successfully.

Okay let's look issue:

- First step is working, so going to the [gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBeAz.png) *I am facing an issue in the second step*
- Second step: when I select an image then VS Code losing connection to the device so the app is crashing. [Emulator Photo When It Crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBEeR.png)

And here is the output:

```
2
D/permissions_handler( 5092): No android specific permissions needed for: 9
D/EGL_emulation( 5092): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa593bf20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa3c2fde0)
D/EGL_emulation( 5092): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa593b380: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x943b5230)
E/eglCodecCommon( 5092): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000087fe
E/MethodChannel#plugins.hunghd.vn/image_cropper( 5092): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.hunghd.vn/image_cropper( 5092): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.gayidayi/com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
E/MethodChannel#plugins.hunghd.vn/image_cropper( 5092):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.hunghd.vn/image_cropper( 5092):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.hunghd.vn/image_cropper( 5092):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4224)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.hunghd.vn/image_cropper( 5092):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.hunghd.vn/image_cropper( 5092):     at vn.hunghd.flutter.plugins.imagecropper.ImageCropperDelegate.startCrop(ImageCropperDelegate.java:91)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.hunghd.vn/image_cropper( 5092):     at vn.hunghd.flutter.plugins.imagecropper.ImageCropperPlugin.onMethodCall(ImageCropperPlugin.java:59)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.hunghd.vn/image_cropper( 5092):     at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.hunghd.vn/image_cropper( 5092):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.hunghd.vn/image_cropper( 5092):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.hunghd.vn/image_cropper( 5092):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.hunghd.vn/image_cropper( 5092):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.hunghd.vn/image_cropper( 5092):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.hunghd.vn/image_cropper( 5092):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.hunghd.vn/image_cropper( 5092):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.hunghd.vn/image_cropper( 5092):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.hunghd.vn/image_cropper( 5092):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
E/flutter ( 5092): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.gayidayi/com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?, null, android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.gayidayi/com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
E/flutter ( 5092):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
E/flutter ( 5092):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
E/flutter ( 5092):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4224)
E/flutter ( 5092):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
E/flutter ( 5092):  at vn.hunghd.flutter.plugins.imagecropper.ImageCropperDelegate.startCrop(ImageCropperDelegate.java:91)
E/flutter ( 5092):  at vn.hunghd.flutter.plugins.imagecropper.ImageCropperPlugin.onMethodCall(ImageCropperPlugin.java:59)
E/flutter ( 5092):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/flutter ( 5092):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/flutter ( 5092):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
E/flutter ( 5092):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 5092):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
E/flutter ( 5092):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/flutter ( 5092):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
E/flutter ( 5092):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 5092):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
E/flutter ( 5092):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
E/flutter ( 5092): )

E/flutter ( 5092): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
package:flutter/…/services/message_codecs.dart:582
E/flutter ( 5092): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:159
E/flutter ( 5092): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5092): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:332
E/flutter ( 5092): #3      ImageCropper.cropImage
package:image_cropper/src/cropper.dart:102
E/flutter ( 5092): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5092): #4      UserServices.uploadProfilePicture
package:gayidayi/…/services/user_service.dart:52
E/flutter ( 5092): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5092): #5      _ProfileState.buildProfilePicture.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:gayidayi/…/main/profile.dart:284
E/flutter ( 5092): #6      _OpacityButtonState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter_button/custom/opacity_button.dart:40
E/flutter ( 5092): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:596
E/flutter ( 5092): #8      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:183
E/flutter ( 5092): #9      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:596
E/flutter ( 5092): #10     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:287
E/flutter ( 5092): #11     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:222
E/flutter ( 5092): #12     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:476
E/flutter ( 5092): #13     PointerRouter._dispatch
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:77
E/flutter ( 5092): #14     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122
E/flutter ( 5092): #15     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:377:8)
E/flutter ( 5092): #16     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:120
E/flutter ( 5092): #17     PointerRouter.route
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:106
E/flutter ( 5092): #18     GestureBinding.handleEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:358
E/flutter ( 5092): #19     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:338
E/flutter ( 5092): #20     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent
package:flutter/…/rendering/binding.dart:267
E/flutter ( 5092): #21     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:295
E/flutter ( 5092): #22     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:240
E/flutter ( 5092): #23     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src
D/EGL_emulation( 5092): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa593b380: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x943b5230)
D/EGL_emulation( 5092): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa593bf20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa3c2fde0)
D/AndroidRuntime( 5092): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime( 5092): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 5092): Process: com.example.gayidayi, PID: 5092
E/AndroidRuntime( 5092): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=69, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.example.gayidayi/com.example.gayidayi.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
E/AndroidRuntime( 5092):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4053)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5092):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4096)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5092):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5092):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1516)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5092):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5092):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5092):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5092):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5092):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5092):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

E/AndroidRuntime( 5092): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
E/AndroidRuntime( 5092):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:139)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5092):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.success(MethodChannel.java:238)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5092):    at vn.hunghd.flutter.plugins.imagecropper.ImageCropperDelegate.onActivityResult(ImageCropperDelegate.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5092):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEnginePluginRegistry$FlutterEngineActivityPluginBinding.onActivityResult(FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.java:691)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5092):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.onActivityResult(FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.java:378)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5092):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onActivityResult(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:625)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5092):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onActivityResult(FlutterActivity.java:583)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5092):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6915)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5092):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4049)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5092):    ... 9 more
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

`flutter doctor` output:

````
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H114 darwin-x64, locale en)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.0)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.53.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```xml
**Version of image_picker i use:**
```yaml
image_picker: ^0.6.7+22
````

**Manifest xml:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gayidayi">
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <application
        android:label="YHQ"
        
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    {com.example.gayidayi/com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity}

</manifest>
```

Comment: run ``flutter clean`` once and try.

Comment: please confirm declare activity in manifirst

Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.gayidayi/com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Not i have no idea how to do that, can you provide some source code or doc? or directly put a answer

Comment: @Steve55 you are using any extra plugin like for cropping image or any?

Comment: Yeah i am using `image_cropper`

Comment: Add UCropActivity into your AndroidManifest.xml

<activity
    android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>

Comment: can you give me full AndroidManifest.xml? so I have updated question with old AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found out a solution for that.
I also faced this issue and this solution helped to me. Here The problem is image cropper package. So image cropper package need a activity permission to add  on `AndroidManifest.xml`, so for android.

**Here is permission:**

```xml
<activity
    android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

Here is [documentation of image cropper](https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper), you can get more by looking